# Combining stylesheets with over-lapping styles?

Tags: html, css

Here's the situation I've inherited: the previous developer decided it was a good idea to create two stylesheets, one called main.css and the other color.css, with color.css being called inside of main.css using @import.

What that means is, there are multiple declarations for the same selector split into multiple rules across these stylesheets.  For example, in main.css there will be:

```
.content_main {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
 }
```

while in color.css there will be:

```
.content_main {
      background-color: #9D937A;
 }
```

This type rule duplication targeting the same selector is repeated through 1136 lines of CSS.

Because I find this to be completely valueless, I want to combine both stylesheets into one stylesheet while preserving the cascade of the style rules when they page is rendered in the browser.

Rather than do this by hand, my belief (rather hope) is that someone has already created either a command line tool or an online tool to do this.  I have researched and found that there are a number of tools to minify, beautify and/or concatenate stylesheets but I have not yet found one to combine and preserve the cascade as I am suggesting here.

If such a tool exists and I missed it, please forgive me in advance.  Likewise, if this specific question has already been answered on SO and I missed it it was not for lack of trying to find it, so please accept my humblest apologies.  Otherwise, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There is no automatic tool for doing this. It's simply the hard work of code-refactoring.

Comment: I think you are probably right, unfortunately.

Comment: have you looked at [SMACSS](https://smacss.com/book/type-theme)? It's a architecture for css that actually suggests that this is done in order to make theming easier - maybe the dev was trying to do that?

Comment: Thanks @ToniLeigh, you may very well be right about that.  And perhaps his attempt was poorly executed as well since I found it to be more of a nuisance than a benefit.

Comment: yeah I tried it and found it confusing in my context, but I could certainly see the benefit in something with heavy theming - also, devs often home-brew their own solutions, I've started asking 'why?' however odd it looks lol

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice online tool to compress CSS that allows you to do that: http://devilo.us/

Simply copy and paste your two files there, and you'll get the merged result.

Another of such tools is http://www.minifycss.com/css-compressor/.

Comment: I tried this online tool and I received this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function addBlock() on a non-object in /home/devilous/public_html/lib/Parser.php on line 517

Furthermore, I don't think this tool actually attempts to combine the styles from both files preserving the cascade as when rendered.

Comment: What about the second one I added?

Comment: Yes, that one worked but the output CSS cascade was reordered so the rendered page layout was messed up.  I'm beginning to think Diodeus is correct: I'll probably have to refactor this manually.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps [**Code Beautifier**](http://www.codebeautifier.com/) might be what you are looking for.